# Yasnippet-snippets indention not correct for Python functions

Tags: python, yasnippet

[Yasnippet-snippets](https://github.com/AndreaCrotti/yasnippet-snippets) contains a snippet for Python mode to create a [function with a docstring](https://github.com/AndreaCrotti/yasnippet-snippets/blob/master/snippets/python-mode/function_docstring). The indention is not correct when I use it, I think it maybe has to do with some Spacemacs settings, but I can not find the source.

Are you using spacemacs and does this snippet indent correctly for you?

See [here](https://github.com/AndreaCrotti/yasnippet-snippets/issues/349) for Github issue.

Comment: Welcome!  Can you edit your post to demonstrate what the snippet is giving you, and what you expect it to give?  Also, you mentioned that you think Spacemacs may part of the problem.  Can you start Emacs without Spacemacs (`emacs -Q`), run the snippet, and check?

Answer (score 0):

You need the following to preserve the spaces or tabs.

```
# expand-env: ((yas-indent-line 'fixed) (yas-wrap-around-region 'nil))
```